# How do I replace the default GRUB bootloader?

Tags: grub2

I have 2 distributions in my PC. Ubuntu and Linux Mint. Linux Mint was installed second, but I work mostly in Ubuntu. 
Whenever I install new kernel in my ubuntu, I have to run update-grub from Linux-Mint to get it updated in Grub screen. Is there anyway to make the GRUB in my ubuntu as the one which loads the operating systems?

Comment: @SreejithMM Yes you can just run `sudo update-grub` on your Ubuntu. If that failed, try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install grub2 grub-pc` and then run the first command(all commands on Ubuntu).

Comment: Major grub updates in Mint may reinstall its grub to MBR. This may work in Mint also. Just unselect all choices. http://askubuntu.com/questions/458572/how-do-i-prevent-one-of-my-partitions-messing-with-lubuntu-grub-entries/458582#458582 And add your own entry in 40_custom to boot the partition or the link that new kernel creates. Then you do not have to run update in Ubuntu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Answer (score 0):

Try Taking a Look here, it should reinstall grub, And most probably fix your problem
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3A_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the links.
I could achieve my purpose using

'grub-install ' command.

Syntax: grub-install --root-directory=X $dev

Where X is the mount point of your partition containing grub files,in this case the partition containing my ubuntu and dev is the hdd device. Eg: /dev/sda