# Triple-boot replace Grub

Tags: grub2

I'm triple booting Ubuntu, Win 7 and Arch. At present I'm using grub installed by Ubuntu.

I would like to replace it by installing Arch's grub.

My question is: Will Ubuntu updates break or replace Grub especially when installing kernel updates? Or will it simply ignore the grub installation?

I'm aware that I would need to update Grub from Arch when Ubuntu has a new kernel.

Comment: On a grub update Ubuntu may restore grub to location specified. You can blank that location, so grub does not reinstall to MBR. http://askubuntu.com/questions/503417/how-to-prevent-ubuntu-from-overwriting-grub-bootloader-after-update/503446#503446 OR: http://askubuntu.com/questions/458572/how-do-i-prevent-one-of-my-partitions-messing-with-lubuntu-grub-entries/458582#458582

Comment: What if I uninstalled the grub package in Ubuntu?

Comment: @ToDo Then you would need to somehow keep track of the Ubuntu Linux kernels to boot in Arch. Loading the opposite configuration file as a menu entry would be the easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a big problem with MBR installations.

You would overwrite the GRUB code in MBR with the one from Arch and load Arch's `grub.cfg` instead of Ubuntu's. Both ideally should be in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` on their respective root partitions, so that every OS has it's own `grub.cfg` that it can maintain independently. To jump to the configuration of the other OS, you could include the following code (replace `848acb77-de99-4288-a62b-2bf9d7fbd643` and `hd0,gpt2` with appropriate values for the other root filesystem) into `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` or what ever mechanism Arch uses and run the script responsible for updating grub.cfg (`update-grub` in Ubuntu):

```
menuentry 'Custom Title' {
    search.fs_uuid 848acb77-de99-4288-a62b-2bf9d7fbd643 root hd0,gpt2
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
    configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
}
```

Of course you shouldn't mix architectures like i386/ia32 with x64/amd64 or x64/amd64 with x64-efi/amd64-efi. Speaking of EFI, with EFI it's even simpler, as every bootloader should use it's own directory to not overwrite each other anymore.

On MBR installations you should make sure that only one system is able to update the MBR, see [odfred's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/503446/40581) on how to do that. But it shouldn't be much of an issue when you can jump from one config to the other.