# GRUB Bootload Default

Tags: 14.04, grub2, bootloader

I installed SteamOS in a dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04 (I had Ubuntu before SteamOS) and my GRUB Boot loader switched over to the SteamOS version. I preferred the Ubuntu one because it was easier to customize (I know they're technically the same thing, but SteamOS is weird and doesn't format some things like Ubuntu does).

How do I specify Ubuntu's GRUB as the default GRUB Bootloader?

Comment: Go into your Ubuntu install, and do `sudo update-grub` in a terminal.

Comment: I've done that. Like I said in the question, it's booting through SteamOS GRUB so updating Ubuntu's GRUB doesn't do me any good.

Comment: Some similar issues: http://askubuntu.com/questions/458572/how-do-i-prevent-one-of-my-partitions-messing-with-lubuntu-grub-entries/458582#458582 AND: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/503417/how-to-prevent-ubuntu-from-overwriting-grub-bootloader-after-update/503446#503446

Comment: Those don't really help for this specific question. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Grub Customizer to set the default GRUB Bootloader. You can find Grub Customizer at https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

Comment: Awesome. I was able to remove and edit the list, but how do I set this list as default for both OS's?

Comment: Sorry, clarify my follow up, I can edit the GRUB for Ubuntu, but the SteamOS GRUB doesn't change if I update that. How do I change the default GRUB or how do I edit the other one (although I'd rather make the Ubuntu one the default)?