# How to chain bootloaders for two Linux distros dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I installed a current (16.04) **Ubuntu-Mate** to

```
/dev/sda5  (ext2) as  /boot
/dev/mapper/sda6_crypt  (crypted)
    /dev/mapper/sda6_crypt  as /
```

...reboot after setup, Ubuntu working nicely. Then equally I installed a [**elemantary OS**](https://elementary.io/) to

```
/dev/sda1  (ext2) as  /boot
/dev/sda1  (ext4) as  /
```

...reboot after setup, Elementary OS working nicely. (However no choice to choose between Linuxes while booting.)

**No what? How do I chain those bootloaders? (in a simple way if possible)**

- nothing fancy, I do want to keep the two Linux distributions separate (no shared ´/home´ or anything)
- Elementary is more for guests, Ubuntu more for work. ➝ Would be nice to have a timeout that loads Elementary OS automatically after *x* seconds, if no other choice made...

(Apologies for such a beginners question. Sure, there's plenty of advice, but much seems outdated, others appear to be endless shell journeys, many focus on (tougher) dual-boot issues windows+linux, etc...)

I hope I didn't get things wrong, that `/dev/sda1` is `/boot` for a linux *and* the very first partition of the entire drive...

**partion table when starting Elementary OS install**
[image: partion table (during elementary install]

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu? But last install will control MBR. You have to decide which grub you want in control. If Elementary, you will have to add lvm2 driver and mount Ubuntu so it can see it and then run `sudo update-grub` in it. Or manually copy boot stanza into 40_custom. If you want it first copy 40_custom to 06_custom. Scripts are run in number order. More details of customized grub: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen and:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

Comment: Thanks you. Feel free, to post your answer as an answer. So no, no `update-grub` anywhere yet. Should I? Is the grub2 (coming with the absolutely fresh ubuntu install) lousy for any reason?  — I didn't know but anticipated that 2nd install (elementary) would „win“. I am unsure why I require lvm (implied by _crypt? but hey, I just want to boot the ubuntu `/boot`, all else from there...). WIll get back to you later... Thank you again.

Comment: Last install does win, but it is not using LVM nor encryption so does not have drivers installed for that. To reinstall Ubuntu's grub `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` from a boot of Ubuntu. Or use Boot-Repair. But updates in Elementary to grub may reinstall its version to MBR. See this to stop that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/458572/how-do-i-prevent-one-of-my-partitions-messing-with-lubuntu-grub-entries/458582#458582